# Как сохранить авторизацию на Vue.js?

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue3

Разрабатываю приложение на Vue.js 3. Делаю запрос к серверу который возвращает id пользователя, логин и токен.

Мне нужно сохранить все эти данные для использования внутри приложения.

Я использую vuex для того чтобы сохранить эти данные.

Сделал такой стейт:

```
state: {
    user: {
        auth: false,
        token: null,
        login: null,
        id: null
    }
}
```

Создал мутацию:

```
mutations: {
    auth_success(token, login, id) {
        this.state.user.auth = true
        this.state.token = token
        this.state.login = login
        this.state.id = id
    }
}
```

И после того как получаю ответ на запрос я вызываю эту мутацию:

```
commit('auth_success', post.token, post.login, post.id)
```

Вопрос: до какого момента vuex хранит в стейте информацию? до обновления страницы?

как сделать чтобы после авторизации в стейте всегда была инфа о юзере?

Answer (score 0):

Vuex хранит только до обновления страницы. Чтобы хранилось вечно, используй `localStorage.setItem`, а чтобы загрузить -- куда-нибудь в `App.vue` `JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(...), ...)`